# Costume Hook says array of elements is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I am trying to create a costume hook that calls `IntersectionObserver` for all of the `li` elements inside a `ref`.

When I just use it in the component, it works great:

```js
const App = () => {

  const array = [...Array(50).keys()];
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  
  
  React.useEffect(() => {

        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((element: any) => {
                if (element.isIntersecting) {
                         element.target.style.color = 'green';
                }
            })

        })

        ref.current.querySelectorAll(`li`).forEach(element => {
            observer.observe(element);

        });
}, [ ]);
  
  return (
    <ul ref={ref}>
        {array.map((_, i) => <li key={i}>{i}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById(`root`))
  .render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

But When I separate it into a costume hook, it says it is not iterable:

```js
const App = () => {

  const array = [...Array(50).keys()];
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  
  const useCostumeHook = (elements) => {
  
    React.useEffect(() => {

        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((element: any) => {
                if (element.isIntersecting) {
                         element.target.style.color = 'green';
                }
            })

        })

        elements.forEach(element => {
            observer.observe(element);

        });
}, [ ]);
  
  }
  
useCostumeHook(ref?.current.querySelectorAll(`li`))
  
  return (
    <ul ref={ref}>
        {array.map((_, i) => <li key={i}>{i}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById(`root`))
  .render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script> <div id="root"></div>
```

Is there a way to do this with just giving the costume hook an array of elements?

**THANKS!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the hook, and pass `ref.current?.querySelectorAll(`li`)`, the `ref.current` is still `null`, so the result is `undefined` which not iterable.

Instead pass a function that would allow the `useEffect` block to get the items when the `ref` is already set:

```
const useCostumeHook = (getElements) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((element: any) => {
        if (element.isIntersecting) {
          element.target.style.color = 'green';
        }
      })
    })
    
    const elements = getElements();

    elements?.forEach(element => {
      observer.observe(element);
    });
  }, []);
}
```

Usage:

```
useCostumeHook(() => ref.current?.querySelectorAll(`li`))
```